# Python pandas dataframe group mean filtered by condition

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to apply the command below to a data frame where the number of groups meet a minimum count criteria.

```
db=table.groupby(['Type','Quarter'])["Price"].mean()
```

So far the below example isn't returning the needed results.

```
db=table.groupby(['Type','Quarter']).filter(lambda group: group.size > 3).groupby(['Type','Quarter'])["SALE_PRC"].mean()
```

Basically I'd like to find the mean of the["Price"] for the (['Type','Quarter']) groups but only if the number of records exceeds 3.

Appreciate any help.
Thank you

Comment: please provide a small reproducible sample data set and your desired data set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `len(group)` for size of `groups`:

```
db=table.groupby(['Type','Quarter'])
        .filter(lambda group: len(group) > 3)
        .groupby(['Type','Quarter'])["Price"]
        .mean()
```

Or use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
db=table[table.groupby(['Type','Quarter'])['Type'].transform('size') > 3]
           .groupby(['Type','Quarter'])["Price"].mean()
```